# What does CASE WHEN EXISTS (select * from table) do? Is there a better way to write this?

Tags: t-sql, query-optimization

I need to resolve an issue with performance of the following query (not my code). It's a section of a larger stored procedure. This particular part is taking a very long time to execute (I just cancelled it after 20 mins) and I don't understand the intent of the case statement in the code. My research to date has only shown examples of checking for a particular column using schema tables, or checking if any records exists using select 1...

This is doing `select *`. Can someone help me to understand the `case when exists` subquery part of this query and if there is a better (more efficient in terms of time to execute) way to write this?

```
INSERT INTO [PaymentStage06]
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                         FROM [transaction] AS [MPT])
                THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'N'
        END AS [DuplicateReleased],
        [MPT].[participantid] AS [ParticipantID],
        [MPT].[courseid] AS [CourseID],
        [MPT].[session] AS [SessionID],
        [MPT].[feedbackcompletedid] AS [TransactionID],
        GETDATE() AS [Refreshed]
    FROM
        [transaction] AS [MPT]
```

Many thanks.

Andrew

I've looked for examples of "case when exists(select *"  but haven't found anything concrete. My guess is it's either checking for the existence of ANY record in that table (in which case why not just select 1), OR it's checking for a match based on all columns, but both of those seem pointless when the outer query is working on the same table. I'm obviously missing the point :)

This is the estimated execution plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1VMU7Goj

According to the execution plan, it is performing a 'left semi join' operation between the inner and outer query. This appears to be like an intersect query...  but still pointless because it's working on the 1 table.

Comment: The `Exists` simply checks if the table `transaction` contains any records, then `DuplicateReleased` will be `Y`, otherwise `N`. But it doesn't make much sense, because it will never be `N`. If it is empty no records are inserted, so you never get `N`.

Comment: In English, the `case` means "Y if there are any rows in transaction or N if there are no rows in transaction". This seems very close to, if not exactly, useless. Tables are empty initially, then (practically always) forever aren't empty.

Comment: The _actual execution plan_ is usually a good place to start with query performance issues. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question. <pedantry> [`Case`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is an _expression_, not a _statement_, in T-SQL. </pedantry>

Comment: thank you everyone, I've removed the subquery as I also think it's pointless, the table will never be empty. Performance is now measured in seconds whereas it previously ran for 50 minutes without completing. The transaction table has 34K rows in it.

Comment: Aside: Using the same alias (`MPT`) for the same table (`[transaction]`) more than once in a query won't make it any easier to understand or debug. It's all the more mysterious since the alias in the subquery was never referenced. It just made it impossible to reference the outer query in the subquery, i.e. to make it a [correlated subquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver16#correlated).